# How to group by date and find consecutive day count

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So I have a table like

```
product date_purchased
apple   2018-08-01
apple   2018-08-02
apple   2018-08-03
apple   2018-08-10
apple   2018-08-11
banana  2018-08-14
```

I am trying to look for how many times the product was purchased on consecutive days. like

```
apple   2018-08-01  1
apple   2018-08-02  2
apple   2018-08-03  3
apple   2018-08-10  1
apple   2018-08-11  2
banana  2018-08-14  1
```

The first column in product, second column is the last date it was purchased and the third column is the days it was purchased consecutively.

[EDIT]: Changed the output format

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm familiar with group by, but I am not sure how do I check for consecutive days and get a count.

Comment: FYI it might be best to call your column `products` as `product` conflicts with the `product` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new key by using `diff` and `cumsum` , then we can `groupby` `agg`

```
df.date_purchased=pd.to_datetime(df.date_purchased)
df['Newkey']=df.date_purchased.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
df
Out[358]: 
  product date_purchased  Newkey
0   apple     2018-08-01       1
1   apple     2018-08-02       1
2   apple     2018-08-03       1
3   apple     2018-08-10       2
4   apple     2018-08-11       2
5  banana     2018-08-14       3
df.groupby(['product','Newkey'])['date_purchased'].agg(['last','count'])
Out[359]: 
                     last  count
product Newkey                  
apple   1      2018-08-03      3
        2      2018-08-11      2
banana  3      2018-08-14      1
```

Update

```
df.date_purchased=pd.to_datetime(df.date_purchased)
df['Newkey']=df.date_purchased.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
df
Out[384]: 
  product date_purchased  Newkey
0   apple     2018-08-01       1
1   apple     2018-08-02       1
2   apple     2018-08-03       1
3   apple     2018-08-10       2
4   apple     2018-08-11       2
5  banana     2018-08-14       3
df.groupby(['Newkey']).cumcount()+1
Out[385]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome. Just be sure to sort your dataframe by `products` and `date_purchased` otherwise the `diff` might not work.

Comment: Awesome!!. How can I edit this to show output days for each date.

Comment: @JohnConstantine what you mean output days ?

Comment: @Wen Sorry, I modified the output in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Find when the dates change and create `date_groups` with the `shift` and `cumsum` functions. Then you can groupby by `product` and `date_group` with the multiple aggregation functionality provided by pandas.

Finally formatting and renaming the columns to match expected output:

```
import datetime as dt

(df.assign(date_group=lambda x: (x.date_purchased != x.date_purchased.shift(1)
                                  + dt.timedelta(days=1)).cumsum()
           )
 .groupby(['product', 'date_group'])['date_purchased'].agg(['last', 'count'])
 .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
 .rename(columns={'last': 'last_date_purchased',
                 'count': 'times_in_a_row'})
)


         last_date_purchased  times_in_a_row
product                                    
apple            2018-08-03               3
apple            2018-08-11               2
banana           2018-08-14               1
```

EDIT:

The desired output changes a bit the strategy to follow. The previous one was simpler and I apologize for the over use of `lambda` functions. I am sure some `pipe` can be used.

The code changes in the sense that now we do not count the elements in each `group_date` but a single `key` in associated to the each day. Also we have to simply `groupby` to use the leverage of the `transform` function.

```
(df.assign(date_group=lambda x: (x.date_purchased != x.date_purchased.shift(1)
                              + dt.timedelta(days=1)).cumsum(),
        key=1,
        times_in_a_row=lambda x: x.groupby(['product', 'date_group'])
                                  .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum())
       )
[['product', 'date_purchased', 'times_in_a_row']]
)

  product date_purchased  times_in_a_row
0   apple     2018-08-01               1
1   apple     2018-08-02               2
2   apple     2018-08-03               3
3   apple     2018-08-10               1
4   apple     2018-08-11               2
5  banana     2018-08-14               1
```

Comment: Awesome!!. How can I edit this to show output days for each date.

Comment: I am very sorry I forgot to add the imports. Let me edit.

Comment: @JohnConstantine what do you mean by output days by each date?

Comment: I modified the output in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178631/discussion-between-john-constantine-and-gonzalo-mr).