# Extract data based on condition

Tags: python, algorithm, dataset, pseudocode, data-extraction

I have the following dataset (sample) from which I have to extract dataframe based on a condition. The dataset consists of machines (over 1000), the downtime in hours, the status, and the downtime reason. There are many instances of each machine in the dataset (at least 1000). *The condition for extraction is the dataframe must only contain those machines that have been active for the past 7 days consecutively (including the date)*. The dataset does not contain records for every day for each machine. Some days have been skipped. For those days, I'm not sure if the machine was active or not. I'm trying to do it on a rolling basis, for example, for  the date in each row, I'm trying to check if that unique machine has been active for the past 7 days (pd.Timedelta(days = 6)). I think there is a neater and more organized way to achieve this but so far, I've not been able to come up with an algorithm. I'm pretty much a novice programmer in Python. Is there someway I can organize the machines and then check for each date. I would also like to be able to keep track of those machines for which records for some days have been skipped. I don't need the code in Python. I'd just greatly appreciate if someone could help me come up with an effective algorithm through which I can achieve the new dataframe.

Thank you very much in advance and happy holidays! :)

| DATE | MACHINE | DT_IN_H | MACHINE_STATUS | DT_REASON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/5/2021 | 710 | 0 | ACTIVE | In Service |
| 8/1/2020 | 847 | 0 | ACTIVE | In Service |
| 2/4/2020 | 1334 | 0 | ACTIVE | In Service |
| 5/16/2020 | 855 | 24 | ACTIVE | Under mgmt |
| 1/4/2019 | 669 | 0 | ACTIVE | In Service |
| 7/24/2021 | 1831 | 0 | ACTIVE | In Service |
| 10/19/2018 | 134 | 24 | ACTIVE | Under mgmt |
| 8/18/2019 | 395 | 0 | ACTIVE | In Service |
| 1/19/2019 | 499 | 24 | ACTIVE | Under mgmt |
| 7/24/2020 | 2085 | 0 | ACTIVE | In Service |

Comment: To allow responders to test their ideas, Stackoverflow much prefers example data to be added as text rather than an image.

Comment: Thank you @DarrylG, I'll amend my question now

Comment: A MACHINE only occurs once in your dataset.  Consequently, no machine appeaers ACTIVE on successive days which makes it harder to check ideas for your desired output.

Comment: If the dataset is large you could use a cloud link to a fuller dataset using a service such as pastebin.com, or many others.

Comment: Don't forget to add a link to the online data.

Comment: Hi @DarrylG, here's the pastebin link https://pastebin.com/QwkJXK7f

Comment: In the larger dataset I'm not finding machines that are active for 7 consecutive days.  By consecutive you mean the same machine with no gaps in the date.  The most I find is 4 days.  An example is MAHINE_NO = 588 found for the four consecutive dates: 2019-05-04, 2019-05-05, 2021-11-03, 2021-11-03 .

Comment: Hi @DarrylG, I'm including another dataset. This is a dataset of one machine. I'm still trying to figure out how to determine if this machine had been in service for 7 consecutive days. Thank you so much for helping! :) https://pastebin.com/L0GSYrjf

Comment: yes, this machine has been in service.  I'll post some code that will help you identify when this is True.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach**

Adapting method from [How to group by date and find consecutive day count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989388/how-to-group-by-date-and-find-consecutive-day-count/51989662#51989662) we proceed as follows

1. Take Dataframe rows only where MACHINE_STATUS is ACTIVE
2. convert DATE column from string to DATE
3. Sort by DATE (ascending)
4. Add a unique identifier for each group of ascending dates per MACHINE
5. Filter to obtain only when group size >= 7

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/L0GSYrjf")    # Read data from url
df = df[df.MACHINE_STATUS == "ACTIVE"]                   # 1 when machine is ACTIVE

df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)                     # 2 Convert data field from string to date
df = df.sort_values(by='DATE', ascending=True)           # 3 sort by date 
df['successive'] = df.groupby(["MACHINE"]).DATE.transform(func = lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()) # 4 add unique identifier

# 5 Filter keeping only groups of 7 or more active
df2 = df.groupby(["MACHINE", "successive"]).filter(lambda g: len(g) >= 7)

print(df2.groupby(['successive']).size()) 
# Output (shows only 1 group of length 1471, which means machine was active for 1471 successive days)
successive
1    1471
dtype: int64

print(df2.head(10))
# Output

       DATE  MACHINE  DT_IN_H MACHINE_STATUS   DT_REASON  successive
0 2018-01-01     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
1 2018-01-02     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
2 2018-01-03     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
3 2018-01-04     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
4 2018-01-05     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
5 2018-01-06     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
6 2018-01-07     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
7 2018-01-08     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
8 2018-01-09     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
9 2018-01-10     1887      0.0         ACTIVE  In Service           1
```

**Using DT_REASON **

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/L0GSYrjf")
df = df[df.DT_REASON == "In Service"]                   # 1 when machine is ACTIVE
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)                    # 2 Convert data field from string to date
df = df.sort_values(by='DATE', ascending=True)          # 3 sort by date 
df['successive'] = df.groupby(["MACHINE"]).DATE.transform(func = lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()) # 4 add unique identifier

df2 = df.groupby(["MACHINE", "successive"]).filter(lambda g: len(g) >= 7)

    df2.head(10)
    # Output shows first 10 of first group
    DATE    MACHINE DT_IN_H MACHINE_STATUS  DT_REASON   successive
0   2018-01-01  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
1   2018-01-02  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
2   2018-01-03  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
3   2018-01-04  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
4   2018-01-05  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
5   2018-01-06  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
6   2018-01-07  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
7   2018-01-08  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
8   2018-01-09  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1
9   2018-01-10  1887    0.0 ACTIVE  In Service  1

df2.groupby(['successive']).size()
# Shows there are groups
successive
1     20
3    113
4    151
5     58
6    386
7    437
8    292
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi @DarrylG, thank you so much for sharing the code itself with me. The column I'm trying to filter by is 'DT_REASON' and when I run the code changing just that one value, I get an empty dataframe. :/

Comment: Hi @DarrylG, I came up with another, perhaps more primitive method. I'm adding a column at the end of the dataframe that contains all the dates for the past week. I guess my idea was to see if the dates in the list are in the present in the column 'DATE', then I'd mark 'TRUE' in another column 'IS_IN_SERVICE'. I'm including that dataset below. I guess my problem here is how can I check the 'DATE' column against a list of dates? https://pastebin.com/049WKWFB

Comment: @Wasp10 -- I'm not sure if I understand how the extra column solves your problem.  I thought you wanted to check if a machine has been continuously active for the past week.  Regarding DT_REASON, were you trying to change from checking if MACHINE_STATUS == ACTIVE to check if DT_REASON = "In Service"?  I don't get an empty dataframe when I do this.

Comment: @Wasp10 -- in above code using DT_REASON instead of MACHINE_STATUS I get 8 different groups of continuous 7 or more days.

Comment: Hi @DarrylG, When I add this statement, I get an empty dataframe -> data = data[data['MACHINE_STATUS'] == 'In Service'] Also, I'm not an advanced programmer in Python. :/ I looked up the functions you used and I'm kind of lost, especially with this statement -> df['successive'] = df.groupby(["MACHINE"]).DATE.transform(func = lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()) # 4 add unique identifier. I get that it's creating a new column 'Successive' and I've looked up the functions individually but what is the unique identifier?

Comment: I get the 8 groups when I omit this statement -> data = data[data['MACHINE_STATUS'] == 'In Service']

Comment: `code #data = data[data['DT_REASON'] == 'In Service']
data['successive'] = data.groupby(["DT_REASON"]).DATE.transform(func = lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()) # 4 add unique identifier

# 5 Filter keeping only groups of 7 or more active
df2 = data.groupby(["MACHINE", "successive"]).filter(lambda g: len(g) >= 7)

print(df2.groupby(['successive']).size()) 

print(df2.head(10)) `

Comment: @Wasp10 - updated by code to use DT_REASON.  In your code example, you didn't sort the values by date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241264/discussion-between-darrylg-and-wasp10).